# Build Vim with lua on Debian 7.8

Tags: vim, lua, debian

I'm trying to build it myself since the version in debian apt-get is too old for a plugin I need, and this plugin needs lua.

I did `apt-get install libtolua-dev`

And am runnning the command

```
./configure --with-features=huge \
        --enable-rubyinterp \
        --enable-pythoninterp \
        --with-python-config-dir=/usr/lib/python2.7/config \
        --enable-perlinterp \
        --enable-gui=gtk2 --enable-cscope --prefix=/usr \
        --enable-luainterp \
```

When I run this command, at some point the program will say `checking Lua version... (cached) 5.0.3` when I actually have version 5.2 installed. When I run the configure I get:

```
checking for lua... (cached) /usr/bin/lua
checking if lua.h can be found in /usr/include... no
checking if lua.h can be found in /usr/include/lua5.0.3... no
```

So I tried to copy all the files from /usr/include/lua5.2 to a new directory /usr/include/lua5.0.3
Then I'll get

```
checking if lua.h can be found in /usr/include... no
checking if lua.h can be found in /usr/include/lua5.0.3... yes
checking if link with -L/usr/lib -llua5.0.3 is sane... no
```

I don't understand how to make it use lua 5.2.

Comment: That copying was a **mistake**. You should **never** mess around in `/usr` like that. You will only succeed in confusing and/or breaking your system.

Comment: What version of vim does the plugin need? What version of vim is available from packages? Does vim support lua 5.2?

Comment: The plugin needs 7.3.885 or later with lua support (it's neocomplete)
With apt get I get version 7.3.547-7
I don't know how to find if Vim supports lua 5.2

Comment: `7.4.488` is available in `wheezy-backports`.

Comment: I just tried this, but this version still has no lua (-lua)

Comment: The `wheezy-backports` packages for `vim-gtk` and `vim-nox` are built with lua support it looks like. The `vim` package might not be though.

Comment: Customizing the Debian sources and rebuilding it on your machine is always an option.

Answer (score 2):

For those who are interested by a manner that worked for me to build vim with lua support and a solid basis to setup spf13 with full Neocomplete support here are the steps followed to do it:

1. Download the vim sources from git:

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/vim/vim.git
   ```
2. Setup dependancies (on ArchLinux, adapt according to your distribution):

   ```
   pacman -Suy ruby perl python2 python lua luajit
   ```
3. Link luajit headers for the compilation:

   ```
   cd /usr/local/include
   sudo ln -sv /usr/include/luajit-2.0/lua.h
   sudo ln -sv /usr/include/luajit-2.0/luaconf.h
   sudo ln -sv /usr/include/luajit-2.0/lualib.h
   sudo ln -sv /usr/include/luajit-2.0/lauxlib.h
   ```
4. Run the following commands to build vim (include lua support as desired):

   ```
   ./configure --with-features=huge --enable-multibyte --enable-rubyinterp --enable-pythoninterp --with-python-config-dir=/usr/lib/python2.7/config --enable-gui=no --without-x enable-cscope --enable-multibyte --enable-fontset --enable-largefile --enable-cscope --enable-perlinterp --enable-luainterp --enable-fail-if-missing --with-lua-prefix=/usr/local/  --with-luajit --prefix=/usr
   ```
5. Compile:

   ```
   make VIMRUNTIMEDIR=/usr/share/vim/vim80
   ```
6. Install Vim:

   ```
   sudo make install
   ```
7. Use vim --version command to verify lua support (+lua):

   ```
   vim --version
   ```

And that's it!

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the `--with-lua-prefix=<dir>` flag when running configure. This flag tells the configure script where lua is installed. (You could also set the `LUA_PREFIX` environment variable if you do not pass the flag).

---

I would also recommend running configure with `--enable-fail-if-missing` so that the configure script will fail instead of quietly warning that it didn't find a lua config directory or executable.

Comment: The problem is then `checking if lua.h can be found in /usr/include/lua5.2/include... no
checking if lua.h can be found in /usr/include/lua5.2/include/lua5.0.3... no
configure: error: could not configure lua`
when I set --with-lua-prefix=/usr/include/lua5.2
Nothing more happens when I set LUA_PREFIX=/usr/include/lua5.2